# Pause After UI Update

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I have a calendar UI ([material-calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)) that is working as I want. When the user selects a date, I am changing the background color of that specific date and then I replace that calendar fragment with another fragment. This all works correctly.

What I would like to do is to show a slight pause *after* the calendar background color is updated. As it works right now, you can only see the background color flash the color change before the fragment is replaced. The color change is almost imperceptible.

Here is the code for how this cell is modified:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView materialCalendarView, @NonNull CalendarDay calendarDay, boolean b) {

                decorateSelectedDate(calendarDay.getDate());

                // some other database stuff happens here
            }
        });

   private void decorateSelectedDate(Date date) {
        List<CalendarDay> list = new ArrayList<CalendarDay>();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        CalendarDay calendarDay = CalendarDay.from(calendar);
        list.add(calendarDay);
        calendarDays = list;
        calendarView.addDecorators(new SelectionDecorator(Color.RED, calendarDays));
    }

private class SelectionDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

        // the point of this class is fill in the background color for the calendar cell
        // just selected by the user

        private final int color;
        private final HashSet<CalendarDay> dates;

        public SelectionDecorator(int color, Collection<CalendarDay> dates) {
            this.color = color;
            this.dates = new HashSet<>(dates);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
            return dates.contains(day);
        }

        @Override
        public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
            // colors the entire calendar space
            Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(color);
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

            // my attempt to add a short delay before replacing the fragments. 5 seconds is way too long, but I'm just trying to prove that this works.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // this invokes a method in the activity to swap out the fragments
            fragmentCommunicator.onNewDateSet();
        }
    }
```

You can see that I have a `Thread.sleep` command immediately after the command to update the UI. However, no matter how long of a delay that I set, the delay happens *before* the UI is updated (it should be the other way around), so the background color change remains just a flash before the fragment is replaced.

How can I get the UI to update *before* the delay is started? Clearly `Thread.sleep` doesn't seem to be the answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay) to defer your action rather than sleep. Generally speaking putting the UI thread to sleep is a bad thing and should be avoided.

See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for more info.

Put your call to the fragment communicator in the delayed runnable. The sleep doesn't work because set background is not synchronous(work is defered to the next draw call which happens after you return from on click) and must be done on the same thread as the one you are sleeping as well as the one running the fragment operations.

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy [Handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

***You can use Handler instead of Thread***

> A Handler allows you communicate back with the UI thread from other
>   background thread. This is useful in android as android doesn’t allow
>   other threads to communicate directly with UI thread. Handler can send
>   and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread’s
>   MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread
>   and that thread’s message queue. When a new Handler is created, it is
>   bound to the thread/message queue of the thread that is creating it.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); // Declare 

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after your times

    handler.postDelayed(this, Your_Delay_Time_INT);
  }
}, 1500);
```

- **While rescheduling Handler is very easy**

Comment: Thanks. Why do you have the line `handler.postDelayed(this, Your_Delay_Time_INT` *inside* the `Runnable`? Doesn't the delay defined on the outer function handle that already?

Comment: This would reschedule the same runnable again. For something that needed to happen repeatedly with the UI this can be a handy trick. Although might not be ideal way for short or interval critical repeats

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the UI, you can't use this thread. You can use UIHandler or Handler. Like this:

```
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
   @oberride
   public void run(){
     fragmentCommunicator.onNewDateSet();
   }
};

view.postDelayed(run, 5000);
```

What you want to delay, you should put your code in this run(). And consider it when users operate in this 5s, you need also write a cancel delay.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using Handle to run a runnable